# Can I use "lock" across projects?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a project and a class library.

I need the class library to update storage items. In my project I need to access these storage items. Can I use `lock` on the same instance from different projects and will this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as you're locking on genuinely the same object, that should work absolutely fine. If you were using different AppDomains things would get more complicated, but if it's just (say) both Project A and Project B locking on an object which originally came from Project C, that shouldn't be a problem.

At least, it'll work *technically*. Personally I usually prefer to keep locks as private as possible - for example, rather than locking on `this` or a reference obtained from elsewhere, I'll often create an object whose *sole purpose* is locking:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly object mutex = new object();

    ...
}
```

That way I know that the *only* code which can acquire that lock is code in `Foo`. It makes the locks easier to reason about.

Comment: thanks Jon. would be that fine by design? alternatively I can recreate "updated" instance in class library, than pass this instance via event to my project. in project i can lock storage and replace outdated instance with updated one. i.e. the question is how to solve the problem where class library should update some storage and project need to use that storage...

Comment: @javapowered: I'd need a *lot* more context to really say - but as I wrote, I would *try* to avoid exposing locks too widely.

Comment: the problem is that I should either expose locks or recreate objects intensively. So I prefer to expose locks to achieve better performance and to have less work for GC (which is pretty annoying when used in HFT software).